# how to display two markers using angular-map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
<ui-gmap-markers idKey=11 coords="'self'"    models='{"latitude":27.703983,"longitude":85.334876}'>
</ui-gmap-markers>
```

i'm new to angular-map.i've to show 2 markers in the map.i'm using gi-gmap-markers but couldn't display the markers.can anybody please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

`models` should be an array of marker objects. Each marker in this array should have its own designated `idKey`, `latitude`, and `longitude`. You might want to follow the example in the markers section of [this page](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api).